# presentModalViewController is not working?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am making an application using two view controlers. When I am  working on my first view I have posibility to go to another view using button "Settings" and method conected to this button looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)Settings:(id)sender{

[self presentModalViewController:settingsHandle animated:YES];
```

settingsHandle is an object of a second view class which is alloceted when the first view is loaded.

My problem starts while I am in a second view and i call method which include NSTimer object. This method is working during hmmm lets say 30 sec but it also can be 5 min, the result of this method is calling  onother view the 3rd one.

Everything goes fine while am waiting for the result of this function in a second view.The result is that i am in a 3rd view.

When, during the method is working I am going to the first view from the second (using `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` )I can see that the method has finished(using NSLOG) but `[self presentModalViewController:thirdview animated:YES];` is not working, just nothing happens.

so to sum up:

Waiting for the result in a secodnview (Succes third view uploaded) 
Waiting for the result in a firstview (fail nothing happens)

And my goal is to make it happens from the firstview!

Comment: Are you using ARC (Automatic Ref Counting)? If so, when the last reference to your timer, probably in your 2. ViewController, goes away, the timer will be deallocated, hence it won't invoke anything.

Comment: No I am not using ARC ;/

Comment: And the "self" of your [self presentModalViewController:thirdview animated:YES]; would naturally be your first View Controller, right?

Comment: But you dismissed it, so you can't present a VC from there. You would have to present it from your first VC. Guess I'm going to create a proper answer :)

Comment: then am waiting coz i dont know how to get the referenc to my first view while am in a second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't present a `ModalViewController` from a `ViewController` that is dismissed. So, you need to keep track of the visible `ViewController` and call `presentModalViewController` from there. In your scenario, the easiest solution would be to make your `NSTimer` invoke a method in your first `ViewController` which goes like this

```
- (void)presentViewController:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(self.modalViewController == nil)
        [self presentModalViewController:settingsHandle animated:YES];
    else
        [self.modalViewController presentViewController];
}
```

If you create the NSTimer in your 2. `ViewController`, you would of course need a reference to the first `ViewController`. You could just pass this reference like this

```
-(IBAction)Settings:(id)sender{
    settingsHandle.myParentViewController = self; //You need to create this var in settingsHandle
    [self presentModalViewController:settingsHandle animated:YES];
    //...
}
```